# Slack returning invalid_auth passport

Tags: oauth, passport.js, slack, slack-api

I'm using passportjs to obtain an oauth token using the following code below:

```
const SlackStrategy = require('passport-slack-oauth2').Strategy;

/* configure passport to work with Slack */
passport.use(new SlackStrategy({
    clientID: SLACK_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    scope: [
        'chat:write:user',
    ],
    callbackURL: SERVER_DOMAIN+"/api/strategy/slack/callback"
  }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    done(null, profile);
  }
));

router.get('/authorize', function(req, res, next) {
  req.session.workflowId = req.query.workflowId;
  passport.authenticate('slack', function(err, user, info) {
    next();
  })(req, res, next);
});

/* OAuth Callback flow */
router.get('/callback', passport.authorize('slack', { failureRedirect: '/authorize' }), function(req, res) {
  const accessToken = req.query.code;
});
```

My problem is that whenever I make a request to the `chat.postMessage` api, I get the following error:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "invalid_auth"
}
```

My full request looks like this:

`https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=xxxxxxxxxxxx&channel=general&text=this is an oauth test...2&pretty=1`

Any idea where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From the api documentation for this method `chat.postMessage` that can be found [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage).

> Some aspect of authentication cannot be validated. Either the provided
>   token is invalid or the request originates from an IP address
>   disallowed from making the request

What you need to do is

1. Regenerate the `OAuth` token.
2. Ensure that you have the right scopes.
3. If you have limited access to specific IP ranges ensure you current IP is within this range. You can also try disabling your VPN if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are doing this here, but if you use os environmental variables, please ensure they are correct and refreshed. I had such issue, but working with Golang. You can simply print the token for a test.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30171656)